# Serial communication over USB port of Pi Zero

Tags: usb, serial

I want to send/receive data between PC and Pi-Zero over USB port near PWR port.

I followed the instructions here https://www.tal.org/tutorials/raspberry-pi-zero-usb-serial-console But I don't enable

> getty@ttyGS0.service

Pi appears as a serial device on Device Manager in Windows with port

> COM13

. I wrote two scripts that will run on each side. 
On pc I have,

```
port = serial.Serial(port='COM13',  baudrate=115200,)
while True:
    num = port.write('hi\n')
    print num
    time.sleep(1)
```

This script successfully opens COM port and prints the number of bytes which is 3 bytes in this case.

On Pi zero,

> /dev/ttyAMA0

appears as a serial device. And the code,

```
port = serial.Serial(port='/dev/ttyAMA0',  baudrate=115200,)
rec = port.read(3)
print rec
```

which opens the port successfully but outputs nothing, gets stuck in `port.read` instruction. What am I missing here?

Comment: try using a serial terminal program in windows, such as `putty` ... do same in linux .... that way you can change the settings easily, such as the baud rate

Comment: do you think that settings don't match?

Answer (score 0):

`/dev/ttyAMA0` connects to either the GPIO serial port or Bluetooth (depending on Pi).

You need to find what device is the USB serial port and use that.

Comment: ```/dev/ttyAMA0``` is the only device when I

```port = [str(port.device) for port in serial.tools.list_ports.comports()]```

Comment: @eminakgn `/dev/ttyAMA0` maybe the only device you see, but there is absolutely no point in trying to use it. You will have to fix whatever you did wrong, but as you haven't explained no one can say.

Comment: I linked the tutorial that I followed. I should not be supposed that explaining all the steps to configure g_serial module which is often used to emulate pi console on PC's serial port. But not to achieve that, I disabled ```getty@ttyGS0.service``` as I have explained. So that I thought I could use that COM port. Nevertheless, Pi is using that port for some reason maybe.When I disconnect DATA cable from Pi Zero, device disappears. So It has to be that port, not GPIO or Bluetooth?